# My HP laptop screen flickers while opening closing the lid. The model is HP ProBook 455 G1. What could possibly be the issue? Any solution to this is?

Tags: display, hp

I have a problem with my HP Probook 455 G1 laptop. When I turn on my laptop it starts flickering wight away and when I move the lid slightly in opening or closing direction it settles down but sometime it settles very difficulty. at certain point it becomes stable and all ok but at some points it starts flickering again. I want to post a video that I made if there is an option otherwise i will share screen shots from the video.

kindly experts guide me that what I need to do? Can it be sorted at home without going to a workshop? Because technicians will always find an easy way and say replace your screen which is a huge expense.

Waiting for a kind response
i am sharing a link of video (shoes screen flickering) that i uploaded on my youtube channel (https://youtu.be/NeoYbCjFKR0)

Regards [screen flickering image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWeYl.png)

Comment: If you're asking "Can it be sorted at home without going to a workshop?" then the answer, obviously is NO, please take it to a professional service if you value the item.

Comment: yeah thanks for the caution but  i opened to check it already. i know a little bit about laptop hardware thats why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a cable (normally ribbon) that flexes back and forth when you open and close the lid.

The cable has likely developed an intermittent open (break in cable) causing this issue.

It is possible also that the cable plug has loosened and needs to be tightened (re-seated). There is likely a plug at each end of the cable.

Ask the shop to evaluate the cost of replacement computer versus fixing it.

Unless you are mechanically adept with small parts and tiny screws, I suggest you get the computer serviced at a local shop.

Comment: yes I can give it a try myself but I will prefer to consult a technician and see if its related to this cable. I opened it a while back but I couldnt adjust the cable so that it gets no shock while opening or closing the lid. I mean its still getting disturbed when i move the lid. thanks for your kind responce by the way.
looks like the issue is exactly like what you pointed out .

Comment: Take care if you decide to do this yourself.  I have taken laptops apart in my basement shop and care is the watchword.